# Замена тега со ссылкой на ссылку

Tags: php

мне в PHP нужно заменить строку

```
<img alt="" title="" src="/upload/rk/c3c/sale_prod.jpg" width="1920" height="474" style="border:0;" />
```

на `/upload/rk/c3c/sale_prod.jpg`

так как для картинок url будет для каждой свой, нужно написать регулярное выражение

я так понял нужно это сделать через str_replace.

Comment: с помощью `str_replace`  вы успешно удалите части `<img alt="" title="" src="` и `style="border:0;" />`, останется выкинуть длину и ширину и еще одну кавычку. Либо после удаления начала строки найти следующий символ кавычки и удалить все, что после него.

Comment: как это сделать?

Comment: У вас просто строка дана, или она в тексте?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$tag = '<img alt="" title="" src="/upload/rk/c3c/sale_prod.jpg" width="1920" height="474" style="border:0;" />';

$url= preg_replace("/^.*src=\"([^\"]*)\".*$/", "$1", $tag);
```

Answer (score 1):

Такие задачи решаются с помощью регулярных выражений:

```
$input_string = '<img alt="" title="" src="/upload/rk/c3c/sale_prod.jpg" width="1920" height="474" style="border:0;" />';

echo preg_replace('/<img.*?src="(.*?)".*?>/i', '$1', $input_string);
```

Если вы будете решать ее с помощью обычной замены текста, то столкнетесь с проблемами, когда атрибуты `width` и `height` будут иметь другие значения.

Живой пример: [repl.it/E9JO](http://repl.it/E9JO)

Comment: в конце регулярки `?>` таки надо на `/>` заменить

Comment: @teran, а зачем?

Comment: а это не конец тэга `img`  у вас?

Comment: @teran, символ вопроса ограничивает жадность квантификатора `*`, очевидно же. И `.*?` включает в себя слэш.

Comment: да, туплю немного :)